# Django auto submit form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to know if I can submit a form in django without user interaction so that it acts just like when a user posts a form. Here is my situation:

1. User submits data to payment gateway.
2. Payment gateway responds with data which has to be validated.
3. User redirected to payment gateway and more data has to be posted to gateway.

One option for me is to render another form for the user after step 2 which can then be used to post the data and redirect for step 3. However the user has to click a button again.

I couldn't find anything relevant to my situation about submitting forms with django.

Is there a way I can do this without the user interacting again for ease of use?

Comment: Can you post your view functions as well?

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for API / AJAX calls.

Comment: @hansTheFranz seems like the way to go thanks.